# Trajectory in a plane field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, rotational-kinematics

Can someone please help me understand this problem with trajectory. It isn't explained very well in book.

$x(t)=a\cos\omega t $

$y(t)=\frac{b}{\omega^2}(1-\cos\omega t)$

$a,b,\omega >0 $ and are constant.

I know that I have to eliminate time in order to get the trajectory, but I don't how to to that. 
The answer in the book is

$y(x)=\frac{b}{\omega^2}(1-\frac{x}{a})$

could someone please explain to me how to get the trajectory ?
And what to look in problems like this when I am asked to find the trajectory? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried drawing a trajectory?

Comment: I have no clue how to do that :(

Comment: Just take $\omega=1, a=2, b=3$. Start drawing for $t=0, t=\pi/2, t=\pi$, etcetera.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint: Try and substitute $cos(\omega t)$ in the $y(t)$ function for something you get from the $x(t)$. Then you should get the equation you provided near the end. You can draw that out as it is linear in $x$.

> I just saw your comment saying you don't know how to draw the trajectory. So to explain, the first two equations you give are parametric equations. They tell you how each coordinate of the particle varies with time. However you want to know the trajectory, i.e. you want to know the path that the particle takes. So that means that you need to describe the motion of the particle in terms of $y$ and $x$. Now using the substitution I hinted at above you will get the final formula that you quote as the solution. It might look convoluted but that is simply a linear equation.
>
> I'm assuming you've seen the general form of linear graphs, i.e $y=mx+c$ where $m$ is the gradient (or slope) of the straight line and $c$ is a the constant which tells you where the line crosses the $y$-axis.
>
> Well the formula you give is identical to this one, try and think what the $m$ and $c$ are in this case?

In general what to look for in these problems is to find a way to substitute the $x(t)$ function into the $y(t)$ function with the aim of getting rid of the $t$'s and so you're just left with an ordinary $y(x)$ function which you can then draw by comparing it to the general linear form, $y=mx+c$, or general quadtratic form, $y=ax^2+bx+c$, (assuming you know how to do this from Math class).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your contribution. Please note, tough, that according to the current [Homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/715/75633), (near-)complete answers are discouraged and [might be deleted](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7641/75633).

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, good edit.

Comment: Thank you for the help, now I understand it. And it's not a homework. So there is no reason for it to be deleted.

Comment: @ZoranMladenovski Glad it helped. Btw I edited my answer and removed the explicit answers and instead hinted at the answers. But the explanation and everything else stayed the same :).